# How to update database's value after pressing button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am currently working on my assignment, I am trying to create a ban system for users, I wanna update the value of `Deleted` in my database to 1 whenever I press the submit button, I tried many on youtube videos but has not given any process

```
$id     = $_SESSION['UserID'];
  $query  = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID='$id'";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  $row2   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  if ($row2['Admin'] == 0) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
  Unfortunately you do not have access to this page 
</div>';
  }
  else {

    $query  = " SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Admin = 0";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="container"><table class="table table-primary table-hover">';
    echo '<tr><th>' . 'NameID' . '</th><th>' . 'Name' . '</th><th>' . 'Email' . '</th><th>' . '</tr>';
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


      echo '<tr><td>' . $row2['UserID'] . ' </td><td> ' . $row2['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row2['LastName'] . ' </td><td> ' . $row2['EMail'] . ' </td><td> '
           . '<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" value="BAN">' . ' </td></tr>';


    }
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      echo '</table>' . '</div>';
      $id     = $_SESSION['UserID'];
      $query  = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID='$id'";
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

      if ($_POST['submit']) {
        $query2 = "UPDATE `Users` SET `Deleted` = '1' WHERE `Users`.`UserID` ='$id'";


      }

    }


  }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: I’m inferring from your code that you haven’t quite grasped the big picture; taking action on the post data doesn’t need to be after you print out the table. In fact, it shouldn’t.   Take care of your post variables first, then redirect back to the same page to display the new results. That way it’s easier to deal with user input on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You define `$query2` but never execute it. This is a common mistake.

> Tip: Don't declare SQL as strings and then run it later, get in the habit of supplying the query as a direct argument to `prepare()`.

For example:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE `Users` SET `Deleted` = '1' WHERE `Users`.`UserID`=?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't run the $query2, do it like this

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
     $query2 = "UPDATE `Users` SET `Deleted` = '1' WHERE `Users`.`UserID` ='$id'";
     mysqli_query($link, $query2);
}
```

Comment: No, don’t do it like this. Never just build a variable into the query string. It should be done as tadman answered. Please be sure that answers are technically correct and adds something unique if there are other answers